# analytics().logEvent() return null and not tracking the event in console

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-analytics

I want to use firebase analytics in react native. I have added the lib,
but when i use the `await analytics().logEvent("event_name")` it returns `null` and event is also not added in firebase analytic console.

Any one have any idea what's wrong?

```
<Button
     title="Add To Basket"
     onPress={async () =>
       await analytics().logEvent('basket', {
         id: 3745092,
         item: 'mens grey t-shirt',
         description: ['round neck', 'long sleeved'],
         size: 'L',
       })
     }
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I started with analytics.

Firebase says it takes around 24 hours for the events to be visible on console.

Also the `logEvent` has a return type of `void`, hence you see `null` being returned. So don't worry regarding that aspect unless you have an error.

So, I would suggest you to wait for the changes to be reflected.

---

For Development purposes we would need to see Realtime events, and Firebase has DebugView for that. For details, refer this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: Thank you for help sir. got it